# Is there a way I can fix this issue with length counter function?

Tags: c++

I have to find the length of an array of characters using a function that uses the pointer notation and, for some reason, I get 23 but the result should be 5.

Here is the code I built:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int length(char *N) 
{
    int length = 0;
    char* S = N;
    for (; *S != '\0'; S++);
    for (; *N != *S; N++)
    {
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}

int main() 
{
    char A[5];
    char *N;
    N = A;
    cout << "please enter the charecters you desire" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <=4; i++) 
    {
        cin >> A[i];
    }
    cout<<length(N);
}
```

Comment: `for (; *S != '\0'; S++);` How will `*S == 0` if you fill the whole array with characters? You need to leave space at the end and explicitly terminate the string.

Comment: `cin >> A[i]` is not likely to ever write a `'\0'` character when `cin` is connected to a terminal where a user can type.

Comment: Looks like you are confused with C++ string, which has a null at the end - but this is an array of chars, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two loops.

And note that you have to leave a space in the array (the last element) to fill it by `'\0'`.

Hence by the two notes and if you want to use five characters excluding the `'\0'`, your code will be as follows

```
#include <iostream>
size_t length(char *N){
    size_t length = 0;
    for (; *N != '\0'; N++){
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}
int main()
{
    char A[6];
    std::cout << "please enter the characters you desire\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        std::cin >> A[i];
    }
    A[5] = '\0';
    std::cout << length(A);
}
```